# Pyspark to map the exchange rate value in dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes df1 and a  a separate dataframe for USD exchange_ratedf2:

#df1#

| from_curr | to_curr | Date | value_to_convert |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AED | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 2000 |
| AED | EUR | 2018-03-20 | 189 |
| UAD | EUR | 2021-05-18 | 12.5 |
| DZD | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 130 |
| SEK | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 1000 |
| GNF | EUR | 2017-08-03 | 1300 |

df2: #currency_table#

| from_curr | To_curr | Date | rate_exchange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AED | EUR | 2017-01-01 | -5,123 |
| UAD | EUR | 2021-05-26 | -9.5 |
| AED | EUR | 2018-03-10 | -5,3 |
| DZD | EUR | 2017-01-01 | -6,12 |
| GNF | EUR | 2017-08-01 | -7,03 |
| SEK | EUR | 2017-01-29 | -12 |

I would like to create a Pyspark function that convert value_to_convert from df1 using the exchange_rate from currency_table (by looking in the exchange_rate dataframe corresponding to the date group from currency ) while joining both dataframes on from_curr field and date field, each value should be converted with rate_exchange from the right date to get df3 like

| from_curr | to_curr | Date | value_to_convert | converted_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AED | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 2000 | 390 |
| AED | EUR | 2018-03-20 | 189 | 35,66 |
| UAD | EUR | 2021-05-18 | 12.5 | 1,31 |
| DZD | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 130 | 21,24 |
| SEK | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 1000 | 83,33 |
| GNF | EUR | 2017-08-03 | 1300 | 184,92 |

converted_value=(value_to_convert)/(|rate_exchange|)
Do you have any idea please?

Comment: so, `-5,123` from df2 should be with `2017-01-12` in df1? how do the values map?

Comment: we map df1 with df2 on from_curr and date, for exemple for from_curr=AED, date=2017-01-12 , we check from_curr on df2, we find two values "AED", we check then Date from df2 if it's in group date of df2 for "AED" we find date=2017-01-01 followed by 2018-03-20 so currency did not change we pick the one that is close to from_curr=AED which means date=2017-01-01, thus converted_value=(2000)/(|-5,123|)

Comment: *Date As of Which the Exchange Rate Is Effective

Comment: what happens in case of UAD-2021-05-18 in df1? does it get mapped to UAD-2021-05-26 from df2?

Comment: Yes because it's the only date on which the exchange rate is effective for this currency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a dirty way of doing it with a `join()`.

```
data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls). \
    toDF(['from_curr', 'to_curr', 'dt', 'val_to_convert']). \
    withColumn('dt', func.col('dt').cast('date'))

# +---------+-------+----------+--------------+
# |from_curr|to_curr|        dt|val_to_convert|
# +---------+-------+----------+--------------+
# |      AED|    EUR|2017-01-12|        2000.0|
# |      AED|    EUR|2018-03-20|         189.0|
# |      UAD|    EUR|2021-05-18|          12.5|
# |      DZD|    EUR|2017-01-12|         130.0|
# |      SEK|    EUR|2017-01-12|        1000.0|
# |      GNF|    EUR|2017-08-03|        1300.0|
# +---------+-------+----------+--------------+

curr_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(curr_ls). \
    toDF(['from_curr', 'to_curr', 'dt', 'rate_exchange']). \
    withColumn('dt', func.col('dt').cast('date')). \
    withColumnRenamed('dt', 'from_curr_start_dt')

# +---------+-------+------------------+-------------+
# |from_curr|to_curr|from_curr_start_dt|rate_exchange|
# +---------+-------+------------------+-------------+
# |      AED|    EUR|        2017-01-01|       -5.123|
# |      UAD|    EUR|        2021-05-26|         -9.5|
# |      AED|    EUR|        2018-03-10|         -5.3|
# |      DZD|    EUR|        2017-01-01|        -6.12|
# |      GNF|    EUR|        2017-08-01|        -7.03|
# |      SEK|    EUR|        2017-01-29|        -12.0|
# +---------+-------+------------------+-------------+
```

We join the the two dataframes on currencies (not on dates), so all exchange dates are mapped to the currencies. From there, we retain the exchange date closest to the currency date using `datediff()`.

```
data_sdf. \
    join(curr_sdf, ['from_curr', 'to_curr'], 'left'). \
    withColumn('dt_diff', func.abs(func.datediff('dt', 'from_curr_start_dt'))). \
    withColumn('min_dt_diff', func.min('dt_diff').over(wd.partitionBy('from_curr', 'dt'))). \
    filter(func.col('dt_diff') == func.col('min_dt_diff')). \
    withColumn('converted_value', func.col('val_to_convert') / func.abs(func.col('rate_exchange'))). \
    drop('dt_diff', 'min_dt_diff'). \
    show()

# +---------+-------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
# |from_curr|to_curr|        dt|val_to_convert|from_curr_start_dt|rate_exchange|   converted_value|
# +---------+-------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
# |      GNF|    EUR|2017-08-03|        1300.0|        2017-08-01|        -7.03| 184.9217638691323|
# |      AED|    EUR|2017-01-12|        2000.0|        2017-01-01|       -5.123| 390.3962521959789|
# |      DZD|    EUR|2017-01-12|         130.0|        2017-01-01|        -6.12|21.241830065359476|
# |      AED|    EUR|2018-03-20|         189.0|        2018-03-10|         -5.3|35.660377358490564|
# |      UAD|    EUR|2021-05-18|          12.5|        2021-05-26|         -9.5|1.3157894736842106|
# |      SEK|    EUR|2017-01-12|        1000.0|        2017-01-29|        -12.0| 83.33333333333333|
# +---------+-------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
```