# Pyspark to map the exchange rate value in dataframe using an exchange rate file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have two dataframes df1 and a separate dataframe for USD exchange_rate df2:

#df1#

| from_curr | to_curr | Date | value_to_convert |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AED | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 2000 |
| AED | EUR | 2018-03-20 | 189 |
| UAD | EUR | 2021-05-18 | 12.5 |
| DZD | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 130 |
| SEK | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 1000 |
| GNF | EUR | 2017-08-03 | 1300 |

df2: #currency_table#

| from_curr | To_curr | Date | rate_exchange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AED | EUR | 2017-01-01 | -5,123 |
| UAD | EUR | 2021-05-01 | -9.5 |
| AED | EUR | 2018-03-01 | -5,3 |
| DZD | EUR | 2017-01-01 | -6,12 |
| GNF | EUR | 2017-08-01 | -7,03 |
| SEK | EUR | 2017-01-01 | -12 |

Do you have any idea about how create a Pyspark function that convert value_to_convert from df1 using the exchange_rate from currency_table (by looking in the exchange_rate dataframe corresponding to the date group from currency ) while joining both dataframes on from_curr field and date field, each value should be converted with rate_exchange from the right date to get df3 like

| from_curr | to_curr | dt | value_to_convert | converted_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AED | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 2000 | 390 |
| AED | EUR | 2018-03-20 | 189 | 35,66 |
| UAD | EUR | 2021-05-18 | 12.5 | 1,31 |
| DZD | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 130 | 21,24 |
| SEK | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 1000 | 83,33 |
| GNF | EUR | 2017-08-03 | 1300 | 184,92 |

I have tried to split the 'Date' field to year and month (same for dt) and join on from_curr and year, month.

Comment: did [this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73080342/8279585) not help you? looks exactly same

Comment: I had to drop dates from df2 ( i kept only date with yyyy-MM-01), because the job failed many times (not enough sources), so i'm trying to have the same  function that match only year and month

Comment: what happens in case there are 2 rates in a year+month? will there ever be such a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the data provided, there aren't any cases where there can be 2 exchange rates in a single year-month for a currency. So, it'll be an easy join if we create a column with just year and month in both the dataframes. *Notice the `yyyymm` fields that I've created in the approach below.*

```
data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls). \
    toDF(['from_curr', 'to_curr', 'dt', 'val_to_convert']). \
    withColumn('dt', func.col('dt').cast('date')). \
    withColumn('yyyymm', (func.year('dt') * 100 + func.month('dt')).cast('int'))

# +---------+-------+----------+--------------+------+
# |from_curr|to_curr|        dt|val_to_convert|yyyymm|
# +---------+-------+----------+--------------+------+
# |      AED|    EUR|2017-01-12|        2000.0|201701|
# |      AED|    EUR|2018-03-20|         189.0|201803|
# |      UAD|    EUR|2021-05-18|          12.5|202105|
# |      DZD|    EUR|2017-01-12|         130.0|201701|
# |      SEK|    EUR|2017-01-12|        1000.0|201701|
# |      GNF|    EUR|2017-08-03|        1300.0|201708|
# +---------+-------+----------+--------------+------+

curr_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(curr_ls). \
    toDF(['from_curr', 'to_curr', 'dt', 'rate_exchange']). \
    withColumn('dt', func.col('dt').cast('date')). \
    withColumn('yyyymm', (func.year('dt') * 100 + func.month('dt')).cast('int')). \
    withColumnRenamed('dt', 'from_curr_start_dt')

# +---------+-------+------------------+-------------+------+
# |from_curr|to_curr|from_curr_start_dt|rate_exchange|yyyymm|
# +---------+-------+------------------+-------------+------+
# |      AED|    EUR|        2017-01-01|       -5.123|201701|
# |      UAD|    EUR|        2021-05-01|         -9.5|202105|
# |      AED|    EUR|        2018-03-01|         -5.3|201803|
# |      DZD|    EUR|        2017-01-01|        -6.12|201701|
# |      GNF|    EUR|        2017-08-01|        -7.03|201708|
# |      SEK|    EUR|        2017-01-01|        -12.0|201701|
# +---------+-------+------------------+-------------+------+
```

The dataframes can be joined on currencies and the `yyyymm` (year-month) fields to map the exchange rates.

```
data_sdf. \
    join(curr_sdf, ['from_curr', 'to_curr', 'yyyymm'], 'left'). \
    withColumn('converted_value', func.col('val_to_convert') / func.abs(func.col('rate_exchange'))). \
    show()

# +---------+-------+------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
# |from_curr|to_curr|yyyymm|        dt|val_to_convert|from_curr_start_dt|rate_exchange|   converted_value|
# +---------+-------+------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
# |      AED|    EUR|201701|2017-01-12|        2000.0|        2017-01-01|       -5.123| 390.3962521959789|
# |      SEK|    EUR|201701|2017-01-12|        1000.0|        2017-01-01|        -12.0| 83.33333333333333|
# |      GNF|    EUR|201708|2017-08-03|        1300.0|        2017-08-01|        -7.03| 184.9217638691323|
# |      AED|    EUR|201803|2018-03-20|         189.0|        2018-03-01|         -5.3|35.660377358490564|
# |      UAD|    EUR|202105|2021-05-18|          12.5|        2021-05-01|         -9.5|1.3157894736842106|
# |      DZD|    EUR|201701|2017-01-12|         130.0|        2017-01-01|        -6.12|21.241830065359476|
# +---------+-------+------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
```

Post this, `select()` the columns that are required in the final dataframe.