# Pyspark to map the exchange rate value in dataframe based on group of values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to convert values from a currency to a currency based on the Following logic:

#df1#

| id | from_curr | to_curr | Date | item_number | value_to_convert |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AED | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 10 | 2000 |
| 1 | AED | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 20 | 189 |
| 2 | UAD | EUR | 2021-05-18 | 10 | 12.5 |
| 3 | DZD | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 10 | 130 |
| 5 | GBP | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 10 | 1000 |
| 5 | GBP | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 20 | 1300 |
| 5 | GBP | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 30 | 500 |
| 6 | EUR | EUR | 2020-09-14 | 10 | 22.50 |
| 7 | EUR | EUR | 2021-09-01 | 10 | 150 |
| 6 | EUR | EUR | 2020-09-14 | 20 | 18 |

df2: #currency_table#

| from_curr | To_curr | Date | rate_exchange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AED | EUR | 2017-01-01 | -5,123 |
| UAD | EUR | 2021-05-26 | -9.5 |
| AED | EUR | 2018-03-10 | -5,3 |
| DZD | EUR | 2017-01-01 | -6,12 |
| GBP | EUR | 2017-01-02 | -0.8015 |
| EUR | CHF | 01-01-2022 | -1.22760 |
| GBP | EUR | 2017-02-01 | -1.02 |

I would like to create a Pyspark function that convert value_to_convert from df1 using the exchange_rate from currency_table (by looking in the exchange_rate dataframe corresponding to the date group from currency ) while joining both dataframes on from_curr field and date field, each value should be converted with rate_exchange from the right date to get df3 like but this time a currency may have two rate of exchanges.

| id | from_curr | to_curr | Date | item_number | converted_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AED | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 10 | 390.39 |
| 1 | AED | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 20 | 19,89 |
| 2 | UAD | EUR | 2021-05-18 | 10 | 1,31 |
| 3 | DZD | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 10 | 21,24 |
| 5 | GBP | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 10 | 1247.66 |
| 5 | GBP | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 20 | 1621.95 |
| 5 | GBP | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 30 | 623.83 |
| 6 | EUR | EUR | 2020-09-14 | 10 | 22.50 |
| 7 | EUR | EUR | 2021-09-01 | 10 | 150 |
| 6 | EUR | EUR | 2020-09-14 | 20 | 18 |

Comment: isn't this same as [this question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73080342/8279585)?

Comment: Nope, actually here we may have two rates exchanges for the same currency, and an id have several values for the same currency.

Comment: Can you check the example of the output cited below?

Comment: okay, some tweaks needed but generally the idea remains the same

Comment: Yes, i used the approach cited here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73082581/15076492

Comment: are you saying there are some currencies that have 2 dates but only 1 exchange rate, and that they get dropped due to the min criterion? i don't think that should happen.

Comment: if you feel the solution doesn't work, please share the use cases (data samples) where you see it breaking. based on the inputs provided, the solution matches the expected output

Comment: Yes, thanks it's turning on the dataset

Comment: There is still a problem, as you can see (in the modified version of my question), the same ID may have several items with different amounts for the same date, after applying the last approach i got the output in my annoncement.

Comment: please update df1 and df2 in the question with your use cases instead of screenshots

Comment: I have updated the dataframes, you can check it please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247559/discussion-between-samkart-and-f-ivy).

Comment: Hello Samkart
There is a problem in the reasoning of the datediff, 
datediff in pyspark returns difference in days between two days
if we have for example a currency for a date: 2011-05-24, two currencies dates: 2011-06-01 and 2011-05-01, the datediff will pickup the date with few days to 2011-05-24, which is 2011-06-01
and this is wrong because the currency we are looking for this example is the one with 2011-05-01