# Get the closest currency rate

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, closest

I would like to join two dataframes based on currency rate exchange and date from the second dataframe. I have tried the approach cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73080342/pyspark-to-map-the-exchange-rate-value-in-dataframe), but the `datediff` gives the difference in dates so it doesn't give me the right rate.

df1:

| from_curr | to_curr | Date | value_to_convert |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AED | EUR | 2017-03-24 | 2000 |
| AED | EUR | 2017-03-27 | 189 |
| DZD | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 130 |
| EUR | EUR | 2020-01-01 | 11 |

df2 (currency_table):

| transacti | local | DateTra | rate_exchange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AED | EUR | 2017-03-24 | -5,123 |
| AED | EUR | 2017-03-26 | -9.5 |
| DZD | EUR | 2017-01-01 | -6,12 |

The output should look like this:

| from_curr | to_curr | Date | value_to_convert | value_converted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AED | EUR | 2017-03-24 | 2000 | 390.39 |
| AED | EUR | 2017-03-27 | 189 | 19.89 |
| DZD | EUR | 2017-01-12 | 130 | 21.24 |
| EUR | EUR | 2020-01-01 | 11 | 11 |

The only method that works is substracting the difference between the two dates "DATE" and "DATETra" and get the closest date to the "DATETra".
Could you please propose another method much cleaner then substracting strings?

Comment: df1 is the main dataframe

Comment: df1 has 40.7 m rows

Comment: and how many in df2?

Comment: there are 14.4k rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could aggregate your smaller dataframe (df2) in order to collect all the dates and rates into one cell. Then, join dataframes, take out what you need and do the division.

Inputs:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(     
    [('AED', 'EUR', '2017-03-24', 2000),
     ('AED', 'EUR', '2017-03-27', 189),
     ('DZD', 'EUR', '2017-01-12', 130),
     ('EUR', 'EUR', '2020-01-01', 11)],
    ['from_curr', 'to_curr', 'Date', 'value_to_convert'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('AED', 'EUR', '2017-03-24', -5.123),
     ('AED', 'EUR', '2017-03-26', -9.5),
     ('DZD', 'EUR', '2017-01-01', -6.12)],
    ['transacti', 'local', 'DateTra', 'rate_exchange'])
```

Script which gets the closest day's rate (could be from future):

```py
df2 = df2.groupBy('transacti', 'local').agg(
    F.collect_list(F.struct('DateTra', 'rate_exchange')).alias('_vals')
)
rate = F.array_sort(F.transform(
    '_vals',
    lambda x: F.struct(
        F.abs(F.datediff('Date', x.DateTra)).alias('diff'),
        -F.unix_timestamp(x.DateTra, 'yyyy-MM-dd').alias('DateTra'),
        F.abs(x.rate_exchange).alias('rate_exchange')
    )
))[0]['rate_exchange']
df = (df1
    .join(df2, (df1.from_curr == df2.transacti) & (df1.to_curr == df2.local), 'left')
    .select(
        df1['*'],
        F.coalesce(
            F.col('value_to_convert') / rate,
            F.when(df1.from_curr == df1.to_curr, df1.value_to_convert)
        ).alias('value_converted')
    )
)
df.show()
# +---------+-------+----------+----------------+------------------+
# |from_curr|to_curr|      Date|value_to_convert|   value_converted|
# +---------+-------+----------+----------------+------------------+
# |      AED|    EUR|2017-03-24|            2000| 390.3962521959789|
# |      AED|    EUR|2017-03-27|             189|19.894736842105264|
# |      EUR|    EUR|2020-01-01|              11|              11.0|
# |      DZD|    EUR|2017-01-12|             130|21.241830065359476|
# +---------+-------+----------+----------------+------------------+
```

Script which gets the most recent rate, but not from future:

```py
df2 = df2.groupBy('transacti', 'local').agg(
    F.sort_array(F.collect_list(F.struct('DateTra', 'rate_exchange')), False).alias('_vals')
)

rate = F.abs(F.filter('_vals', lambda x: x.DateTra <= F.col('Date'))[0]['rate_exchange'])
df = (df1
    .join(df2, (df1.from_curr == df2.transacti) & (df1.to_curr == df2.local), 'left')
    .select(
        df1['*'],
        F.coalesce(
            F.col('value_to_convert') / rate,
            F.when(df1.from_curr == df1.to_curr, df1.value_to_convert)
        ).alias('value_converted')
    )
)
df.show()
# +---------+-------+----------+----------------+------------------+
# |from_curr|to_curr|      Date|value_to_convert|   value_converted|
# +---------+-------+----------+----------------+------------------+
# |      AED|    EUR|2017-03-24|            2000| 390.3962521959789|
# |      AED|    EUR|2017-03-27|             189|19.894736842105264|
# |      EUR|    EUR|2020-01-01|              11|              11.0|
# |      DZD|    EUR|2017-01-12|             130|21.241830065359476|
# +---------+-------+----------+----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Can you explain me this line please? df2 = df2.groupBy('transacti', 'local').agg(
    F.sort_array(F.collect_list(F.struct('DateTra', 'rate_exchange')), False).alias('_vals')
)

Comment: That creates groups by 'transacti' and 'local'. All the values inside the group are aggregated (pushed into a list, so you don't lose them). That list is not a simple list, but list of structs. every struct contains both columns ('DateTra', 'rate_exchange').

Comment: Thank you, when i launch the build i'm having the following error message: Shuffle stage failing due to executor loss, adding EXECUTOR_CORES_MEDIUM is locked, i can't use it

Comment: I can't see why you could be getting this. Not much changed from yesterday's approach. I have checked the execution plans, they have no differences in terms of complexity.